# Take screenshot while clicking and holding a web element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web element with a focus skin, which displays only on click and hold. How is it possible to click the element and hold, and capture a screenshot before release?
The code i have tried so far is:

```java
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("btn1"));     
act.clickAndHold(ele);
<capture screenshot>
act.release(ele);
```

This does take the screenshot, but the above code clickAndHold doesn't hold the click on that element. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe that's a dumb question, but do you need to take the screenshot _in code_? Is this supposed to be a feature of the web site, or do you need the screenshot for documentation only?

Comment: I need to take the screen shot for documentation only

Comment: In this case, why don't you use a utility program for this? Most have a delay/timer function, allowing you to start the timer, interact with the GUI, and wait until the screenshot is taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference [here is the documentation on Actions](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#A_single_action).

I think you're missing some steps in your actions:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("btn1"));     
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(ele);
// Any other actions you want to build onto this
// eg. builder.moveToElement(ele)
//        .release(ele)
//        .etc...
// Now build and get the Action
Action action = builder.build();
// Perform the action(s)
action.perform();
// Take your screenshot
// Build the release action
builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.release(ele);
// Get the built action and perform
action = builder.build();
action.perform();
```

That can get complicated and tiresome. You might want to consider creating a new class extending Actions that adds a take screenshot method you can call and then your code could be simplified to something like:

```
WebElement elm = driver.findElement(By.id("btn1"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(elm).takeScreenshot().release(elm);
builder.build().perform();
```

I don't have a compiler or IDE to test this, but it should work.

Here's what eventually worked for the OP:

```
WebElement elm = driver.findElement(By.id("btn1"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action act = builder.clickAndHold(elm).build();
act.perform();
try {
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\Img\\screenshot.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
act = builder.release(elm).build();
act.perform();
```

Comment: I tried out as per what you said. Extending the Actions class adding TakeScreenshot method, but i'm not able to call in sequence as below    builder.clickAndHold(elm).takeScreenshot().release(elm);

Comment: Why are you "not able to call in sequence as below"? Is it failing to compile? Generating an error during execution? If it's not compiling, make sure your "TakeScreenshot()" method signature matches the "clickAndHold" and "release" methods. Namely the return types are the same. Or is the "builder.build().perform()" line failing? Please provide more information that just "it's not working".

Comment: the signature of "takeScreenShot()" method matches other methods of Actions Not an issue with that. Compiles very well. The problem occurs with "builder.build().perform()". The other sequence which i tried is Actions1 act = new Actions1(driver); ((Actions1) act.clickAndHold(ele)).takeScreenshot(driver).release(ele).build().perform(); Here Actions1 extends the Actions class in which i have defined "takeScreenshot()" method. While execution the "clickAndHold" works but the screenshot which it needs to capture at the focused moment, it doesn't. The screenshot captured is before "clickAndHold()"

Comment: I have modified the above code and it works fine with separate action method to perform() the sequence of Actions methods.  Take the screenshot() call before release() method.

Comment: @nitin chawda, if the above code is not correct, can you provide what worked for you and I can update the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screen capture this way

```java
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\career.jpg"));
```

Comment: what i exactly want is when i click on that element before releasing the click, i need to capture the screenshot. I know how to take screenshot, but the above code clickAndHold doesn't hold the click on that element. how do i do that?

Comment: what are you expecting when u click and hold the webelement

Comment: It has a focus skin, which displays only on click and hold

Comment: Well I thought I'd try it out myself, but cant think of any website that has such a functionality.